# React: can't access passed props (but CAN access props from router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-component

A child component called Edit is receiving props.match from the route ('/:id/edit') but I cannot access other props in `<Edit />` sent from the parent component `<Chirp />`.

Is it not possible to send props with both methods?

My initial problem was that I wanted to access props from `<Edit />` without rendering everything in Edit on the Chirp page.  So I sent the props on Edit's button click. `<Edit />` is rendering all its html fine otherwise.

console.log(this.props) shows Match, Location, and History. I've tried this.props.match.params and this.props.user, etc. but only get undefined.

Chirp.jsx (parent - also a child component)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import Edit from './edit';

class Chirp extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            user: "",
            text: ""
        }
        this.editClick = this.editClick.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    user: data.user,
                    text: data.text
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    }

    editClick() {
        <Edit user={this.state.user} text={this.state.text} />
        console.log("props passed")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Fragment>
                    <Link to="/" className="homelink" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>Home</Link>
                </Fragment>
                <div className="current">
                    <div className="flex-column">
                        <div className='chirps'>
                            <p>{this.state.user}: {this.state.text}</p>
                            <Fragment >
                                <Link to={`/${this.props.match.params.id}/edit`}><button onClick={this.editClick}>Edit</button></Link>
                            </Fragment>
                            <Fragment >
                                <Link to={`/${this.props.match.params.id}/delete`}><button className="delete">x</button></Link>
                            </Fragment>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Chirp;
```

edit.jsx (child component)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

class Edit extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            newUser: "",
            newText: ""
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <Fragment>
                    <Link to="/" className="homelink" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>Home</Link>
                </Fragment>
                <h2>Edit Your Chirp</h2>
                <div className="input">
                    <form action="">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={this.props.user}
                            size="10"
                            id="user"
                            name="user"
                        // onChange={this.inputHandler}
                        // defaultValue={this.props.user}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={this.props.text}
                            size="60"
                            id="text"
                            name="text"
                        // onChange={this.inputHandler}
                        // defaultValue={this.state.text}
                        />
                        <button
                            onClick={this.editChirps}
                            id="submit">
                            Submit
                    </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        )

    }
}

export default Edit;
```

app.jsx

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home'
import Chirp from './chirp'
import Edit from './edit'
import Delete from './delete'

class Navigation extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/:id/edit" component={Edit} />
                        <Route path="/:id/delete" component={Delete} />
                        <Route path="/:id" component={Chirp} />
                    </Switch>
                </Fragment>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: `editClick` is a no-op here; you create and discard a component and return `undefined`. I think what you meant to do is set a flag saying you're editing, and check that flag to decide whether or not you should render the edit component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem is that props were not getting passed to the `<Edit />` component in the router Link. The most efficient solution comes from this YouTube:  [Pass Props To React Router Link Component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmbX2QL7ZJc)

Simply add properties to "to" in the Link with the syntax below. Pass props in 'state'.

```
<Link to={{
     pathname: `/${this.props.match.params.id}/edit`,
     state: {
          user: this.state.user,
          text: this.state.text
     }
     }}>
     <button onClick={this.editClick}>Edit</button>
</Link>
```

Then on the Link (child) component, access the props with

```
this.props.location.state.user
this.props.location.state.text
```

Another solution presented on this page will also work; Instead of defining the route for this Link in app.jsx, define it in the parent component. This would require a few more steps:

import Route, Switch, & Edit
rearrange the Route structure in render; i.e. wrap return in `<Router >`, move home Link, etc
add this inline function to the route: `render={route => <Edit match={route.match} user={this.state.user} text={this.state.text}`

But an issue this method presents is that the home link and chirp 'user' and 'text' show in the Edit component.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `render` a component `onClick` like that.
Plus, `editClick` is not returning anything.

My suggestion is to store a Boolean in state like `isEditMode` and [conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) the component:

```
editClick(){
  this.setState(state => ({isEditMode: !state.isEditMode}));
}
```

and in render:

```
{this.state.isEditMode && <Edit user={this.state.user} text={this.state.text} />}
```

Here is a small running example:

```js
const Edit = ({ someProp }) => <input placeholder={someProp} />;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isEditMode: false };

  toggleEdit = () =>
    this.setState(state => ({ isEditMode: !state.isEditMode }));

  render() {
    const { isEditMode } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleEdit}>Toggle Edit</button>
        {isEditMode && <Edit someProp="Edit me" />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**Edit**
After you update, i now see that your problem is the way you render the `Route` for `<Edit />`.

You are not passing any props:

```
 <Route path="/:id/edit" component={Edit} />
```

You can use the [render prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func).

The issue here is that your data for this component is not at the root component, but that's ok as you can render a `<Route />` at any level down the component tree.

You can see a running example in [this snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/386yn58np1)

Comment: tried this; still not getting any value for user or text props

Comment: I think your problem is with your routing, the place where you render `<Route match="/:id/edit"><Edit /></Route>`. can you post it as well?

Comment: may have found an answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmbX2QL7ZJc    ... trying to implement

Comment: using render on the link gives me this error: Invalid value for prop `render` on <a> tag.  If I use render on the routes in app.jsx, how would I access props from `<Chirps />`?

Comment: @Christy the render prop is not for the `Link` its for the `Route`. Have you seen the example i made (or read the documentation i posted)?

Comment: yes, I've been STUDYING your posts this whole time. I still don't get how to access the parent's prop in `<Route ... `  -- your example's 'someProp' . Anyway, noting state in `<Link>` as I posted seems much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the child component is that you have defined the constructor method inside it without passing props to the super and constructor method for parent component.This way you will never get the props inside child component .

There are two solution of it.

1) Remove constructor method from the child component 
2) If you don't want to remove the constructor for some reason then simply pass props to the super and constructor method in it .

Example :

```
class Edit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        newUser: "",
        newText: ""
    }
 }

 render() {
    console.log(this.props)
 }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem